# Flutter StreamBuilder with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I'm making a chat app and I've just created the chat page with the receiver. And this is the StreamBuilder to get the chat messages, where "chatControllerProvider" is a riverpod Provider which takes with "getChatMessages" all the chat messages from Firebase.

Firebase is structured in this way: users/useruid/chats/receiveruid/messages/messageuid

```
Widget _buildMessages() {
  return Expanded(
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).getChatMessages(widget.receiver.uid),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return MessageTile(message: snapshot.data![index]);
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

And this is the getChatMessages stream:

```
  Stream<List<MessageModel>> getChatMessages(String receiverId) {
    return firestoreInstance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(authInstance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(receiverId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("dateTime")
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => MessageModel.fromMap(e.data())).toList());
  }
```

What I noticed is that it appears the CircularProgressIndicator loading widget permanently. It keeps loading infinitely and I don't see the data which seems to be null (but the messages collection is not empty).

I tried to log the senderId and receiverId and they are correct.

Comment: Do not build the Stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder!  That will reset every time the page rebuilds, up to 60 times per second if there's animation.  See my video for details: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: I see no reason why you'd have a permanent loading here. There's likely something else at play. For instance, you never handle errors in your code. Maybe there is an error

Comment: Ohh thank you! I checked if snapshot has error, and it says "type Timestamp is not a subtype of type DateTime", so I fixed, thank you!